# Ошибка при попытке повторно заменить существующий node

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Задача такова - Даны два select. В первом находятся страны, во втором - города. Сделайте так, чтобы когда выбирается определенная страна - в другом select появлялись города этой страны. В абзац ниже пишите выбранную страну и город через запятую

В первый раз, когда меняю страну - города с новым selectom подставляются без проблем, после второй попытке смены страны появляется ошибка

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceWith' of null

Код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="countries" id="countries">
        <option value="rus">Россия</option>
        <option value="usa">США</option>
        <option value="aus">Австралия</option>
    </select>
    <select name="cities" id="cities">
    </select>
</body>
</html>

<script>

    const countriesAndCities = {
        rus: ['Москва', 'Питер', 'Волгоград', 'Новгород'],
        usa: ['Лос-Анджелес', 'Нью-Йорк', 'Майами'],
        aus: ['Город 1', 'Город 2', 'Город 3', 'Город 4'] 
    }

    document.querySelector('#countries').addEventListener('change', () => {

        const country = document.querySelector('#countries').value;
        let select = document.createElement('select');
        for (let i = 0; i < countriesAndCities[country].length; i++) {
            let option = document.createElement('option');
            option.textContent = countriesAndCities[country][i];
            select.append(option);
        }

        document.querySelector('#cities').replaceWith(select);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: тогда удалите вопрос, либо напишите сами себе ответ  и пометьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключалось в том, что когда создавал новый select - не присваивал ему id cities. Поэтому при второй попытке смены js не мог найти данный select без id

Answer (score 0):

```js
const countriesAndCities = {
  rus: ['Москва', 'Питер', 'Волгоград', 'Новгород'],
  usa: ['Лос-Анджелес', 'Нью-Йорк', 'Майами'],
  aus: ['Город 1', 'Город 2', 'Город 3', 'Город 4'] 
}

document.querySelector('#countries').addEventListener('change', () => {

  const country = document.querySelector('#countries').value;
  let select = document.createElement('select');
  select.id = "cities";
  for (let i = 0; i < countriesAndCities[country].length; i++) {
      let option = document.createElement('option');
      option.textContent = countriesAndCities[country][i];
      select.append(option);
  }

  document.querySelector('#cities').replaceWith(select);
});
```

```html
<select name="countries" id="countries">
  <option value="rus">Россия</option>
  <option value="usa">США</option>
  <option value="aus">Австралия</option>
</select>
<select name="cities" id="cities">
</select>
```